# Type literals only with properties from known type

Tags: typescript

```
interface SomeInterface{
    p1: string;
    p2: number;
    p3: ComplexType;
}

const x :SomeInterface = {
    p1: 'test',
    p2: 'test',
    p3: {//something}
}
```

Now, is there a way to write a generic function like:

```
function foo<T>(parameter:T){

}
```

which would be called using object literal

```
{
...
}
```

but only properties that exist on `SomeInterface` would be allowed? Its important, not all properties must be in a literal call. Call could be done with:

```
{
    p1: 'only one'
}
```

But call with:

```
{
    propertyNotOnInterface: 'bla'
}
```

should get compiler error.

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), like so:

```
function foo(parameter: Partial<SomeInterface>) {
    ...
}
```

Then this is fine:

```
foo({
    p1: 'only one'
});
```

But this:

```
foo({
    propertyNotOnInterface: 'bla'
});
```

Results in this error:

> Argument of type '{ propertyNotOnInterface: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial'.
>    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'propertyNotOnInterface' does not exist in type 'Partial'.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks a bunch!